# Wizard WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, wizard

I am using the Wizard WordPress theme. One of the features it provides is a hamburger button/menu. Is there anyway to change the size of the hamburger button/menu?

Comment: you are not likely to get such a generic question answered here. Please provide some specific code ( html markup, css ) together with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the size of the hamburger icon in css:

```
name-of-icon {
width:22px;
height:22px;
}
```

To get the name of the icon, select the hamburger icon on the browser, click right mouse button, select "examine" (may be other name), then on the opening window you see all css rules for the icon and you will find the name of the icon.

Most Themes have the possibility to adjust css.